# iteration over a sequence with an implicit type in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I am trying to iterate over a sequence of numbers. I have this:

```
from itertools import islice, count
handle = int(input("Please enter a number:")
handler = str(handle)
parameter = []
for i in handler:
    parameter.append(i)
    print(parameter) #This was for debugging
    revised = parameter(count(1[2])) #I'm not sure I'm using the correct syntax here, the purpose is to make revised == parameter[0] and parameter[2]
```

Ultimately, what I am trying to achieve is to take a sequence of numbers or two, and compare them. For instance, if i[0] == i[1] + i [2] I want to return True, or for that matter if i[0] == i[1] - i[2]. I want the program to iterate over the entire sequence, checking for these types of associations, for instance, 23156 would == true because 2*3 = 6, 2+3 = 5, 5+1 = 6, 2+3+1=6; etc. It's strictly for my own purposes, just trying to make a toy.

When I utilize 
    revised = parameter(count(1[2])
I am getting an error that says builtins. TYPEERROR, type int is not subscriptable but I explicitly turned the integer input into a string.

Comment: "int is not subscriptable" points to the fact that you are attempting to index `1` when you do this `1[2]`. You are using `count` as a variable here. Are you trying to use the `.count()` method?

Comment: According to your comment, why don't you simply write `revised = parameter[0], parameter[2]`? (However this will still fail until the third loop iteration, until then `parameter[2]` doesn't exist)

Comment: no i'm trying to iterate, for instance if i have index 0, i want it to compare through the len(handler) and perform the appropriate calculations. for instance, and i know this isn't in the code yet, if index[0] = index [1] + index [2] I want it to print("True"). @mkrieger the reason I can't do it that way is the length of the sequence of numbers is undetermined, I can't hard code it. I need it to iterate through the numbers though. The reason I tried to hardcode it this way is because this is a prototype.

Comment: @rahlf I see, I'm using the wrong method and syntax. well that doesn't help.

Comment: You need to clarify this part of your question, it doesn't make any sense: "23156 would == true because 2*3 = 6, 2+3 = 5, 5+1 = 6, 2+3+1=6". What are your exact requirements here? It's best to bullet point them prior to attempting to write your code.

Comment: I want to make sure each number is itself, or in combination with an adjacent sequence of numbers the sum of or multiples of another number. So, 2*3=6, 2+3+1=6, 5+1 = 6, so for my requirement it is true. The moment this pattern stops, I want it to be false. So, 231562 is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Albeit unclear, what you have attempted to describe is hard to explain.  It appears to be akin to a [Running Total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) but with restrictions and of various operations, i.e. addition, subtraction and products.

Restrictions

- The first two numbers are seeds
- The following numbers must accumulate by some operation
- The accumulations must progress contiguously

**Code**

```
import operator as op
import itertools as it


def accumulate(vals):
    """Return a set of results from prior, observed operations."""
    adds = set(it.accumulate(vals))                        # i[0] == i[1] + i[2]  
    muls = set(it.accumulate(vals, op.mul))                # i[0] == i[1] * i[2]  
    subs = {-x for x in it.accumulate(vals, func=op.sub)}  # i[0] == i[1] - i[2]
    #print(adds, muls, subs)
    return adds | muls | subs


def rolling_acc(vals):
    """Return accumulations by sweeping all contiguous, windowed values."""
    seen = set()
    for i, _ in enumerate(vals):
        window = vals[i:]
        if len(window) >= 3:
            seen |= accumulate(window)
    return seen


def is_operable(vals):
    """Return `True` if rolling operations on contiguous elements will be seen."""
    s = str(vals)
    nums = [int(x) for x in s]
    ahead = nums[2:]
    accums = rolling_acc(nums)
    #print(ahead, accums)
    return len(set(ahead) & accums) == len(ahead)
```

Tests

```
assert is_operable(23156) == True
assert is_operable(21365) == False                         # {2,3} non-contiguous
assert is_operable(2136)  == True
assert is_operable(11125)  == True
```

Comment: You didn't quite get the number sequencing right, but you have provided a very insightful and useful answer that I can study while I try to solve this problem and I thank you for that. It is a little more advanced than I understand, but reading the documentation should resolve that issue, thank you so much!

Comment: Sure.  Can you indicate what you see  to be incorrect?

Comment: No, haha, I was wrong. All this thinking about numbers had me a bit mixed up about my own thinking. I was going to say that 21365 was True, except it isn't because 5 is not a sum or product of the number near it. It would be false also if it was 213652 but true if it was 213651. Thanks again, I voted up this answer but my reputation is too low to mean anything.

Comment: You may be able to accept answers.  Do you need any explanations?

Comment: I think I understand the jist of what is going on, at least well enough to derive the meanings of the definitions. I do not know what using an _ in a for loop does though; however, I will look into this. Sorry for the delayed response, I have been away from my desk so to speak.

Comment: i also cannot figure out how to accept an answer, but once again this is a great post thanks so much.

Comment: There's usually a green tick mark next to each post.   

The `_` is a variable just like `x` or `i`.  It is a convention used as substitute or placeholder to say "I don't care what this value is."  In this case, I'm using the idiom `i, _ for in enumerate(iterable)` because we only care about the index `i`.  It is equivalent to `i for i in range(len(iterable))`.